# get the name of a png image using glob and rsplit

Tags: string, python-3.x, glob

l have a set of images as follow :

```
1234_hello_BV56.png
1256_how_5t.png
```

l want to store in variable

**labels** only the names between `'_'`
to get  `hello` , `how`

**rest_left** 1234 1256

**rest right** BV56 5t

to sum up.
for input like  :

```
1234_hello_BV56.png
```

l want to get the following :

label=hello

rest_left=1234

rest_right=BV56

to do so l tried the following

```
import os
import glob


os.chdir(path)
images_name = glob.glob("*.png")
```

**first try**

```
set_img = set([x.rsplit('.', 1)[0] for x in images_name])
```

it only separte the whole world from png extenxion.

**second try**

```
label,sep,rest = img.partition('_')
```

It returns the first sequence before the firts **'_'**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

```
In [304]: left,labels,right = list(zip(*[os.path.splitext(x)[0].split('_')
                                         for x in images_name]))

In [305]: left
Out[305]: ('1234', '1256')

In [306]: labels
Out[306]: ('hello', 'how')

In [307]: right
Out[307]: ('BV56', '5t')
```

---

Is that what you want?

```
In [266]: [os.path.splitext(x)[0].split('_') for x in images_name]
Out[266]: [['1234', 'hello', 'BV56'], ['1256', 'how', '5t']]
```

Comment: then l need to make in append list to get three separated lists : labels=[hello, how]  left=[1234,1256] right=[BV56,5t]